# Split String and add to a char array?

Tags: java, arrays, string, char

I have for example the following `String` input to my program:

```
"stringToRemoveCharsFrom, f d s a"
```

I want to split the string into the following 2 strings:

```
1. the string before the comma - i.e. stringToRemoveCharsFrom
2. the string after the comma - i.e. f d s a
```

I know that I can do this using `.split()` method and add to an `array / arraylist.`

However, how then can I determine which string is the one before the comma and which is the one after?

I.e. I want to then create a char array from the second `"f d s a"` string - but how to determine which of the 2 strings to create the array from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String str = "stringToRemoveCharsFrom, f d s a";
```

The first one in the array is the one before the comma.

```
String[] vals = str.split(",");

System.out.println(vals[0]); // first part
System.out.println(vals[1]); // second part.

char[] s = vals[1].toCharArray(); // your character array.
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s));
// or if you want an array of single char strings.
String[] st = vals[1].split("");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(st));
```

Your arrays will have space characters in them, if you don't want that
you can do the following.

Strings

```
String[] charsNoSpaces = vals[1].trim().split("\\s+");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(charsNoSpaces));
```

Chars

```
char[] charsNoSpaces2 = vals[1].replaceAll("\\s+","").toCharArray();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(charsNoSpaces2));
```

Answer (score 0):

The first string (before the comma) will be at the first index of the array returned by split (e.g. `0`). The string after the comma will be at the second index (e.g. `1`). Something like,

```
String str = "stringToRemoveCharsFrom, f d s a";
String[] tokens = str.split("\\s*,\\s*");
System.out.println("left = " + tokens[0]);
String[] charTokens = tokens[1].split("\\s+");
System.out.println("right = " + Arrays.toString(charTokens));
```

Which outputs

```
left = stringToRemoveCharsFrom
right = [f, d, s, a]
```